# Does scrapy item exporter support priority? If yes how?

Tags: python-2.7, screen-scraping, scrapy

By supporting priority I mean when you pop an item out of item pipeline it returns an item with highest priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can customize it yourself.

pipelines.py

```
class PriorityPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'soufun.pipelines.PriorityPipeline',
]
```